# How to convert Unmanaged<CFTypeRef> to Swift 3

Tags: swift, pointers, unmanaged

How to override this function from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3

```
 let unmanagedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)

 let phones: ABMultiValue = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedPhones.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValue
```

Compiler says:`'Unmanaged<CFTypeRef>?' has no member 'toOpaque'`

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AddressBook framework is deprecated as of iOS9, and at any time Apple
>   would say: "AddressBook is actually removed from iOS 10.x". You better
>   get ready for Contacts framework soon.

You are using so redundant code that some parts are not needed even in Swift2.

To retrieve `T` object from `Unmanaged<T>?`, you just need to call `takeRetainedValue()` or `takeUnretainedValue()` immediately.

```
let phones: ABMultiValue? = unmanagedPhones?.takeRetainedValue()
```

- You should use `takeRetainedValue()` for the result of `Copy`-ruled functions.
- `ABMultiValue` is a typealias of CFTypeRef in Swift3, so you have no need to cast the result.
- Care about nil-safe coding, as `Unmanaged<T>?` may be nil.